# Remove duplicate row from dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to remove duplicate rows from dataframe based on name and gender. Suppose I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['A','B','A','C','A'],
    'age':[1,6,2,3,4],
    'gender': ['F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M']
})
```

What i want is to delete A on index 0 and 4.And keep the A which is on index 2.
[image]

Comment: `df=[{'name':['A','B','C','A'],'age':[1,2,3,4]}]` is just a dictionary. do you have a dataframe with lists in the columns?

Comment: @anky i want to delete the 'A'  from the name column and 4 from the age column.

Comment: so `df1.drop_duplicates('name')` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? @prashantchhetri Read the documentation.

Comment: @Vishnudev i have attached the screenshot and highlighted the row that i want to delete.

Comment: How did you come to conclusion that you wanna keep the value at index 2?? @prashantchhetri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop duplicates using a subset of two columns. You'll need to consider both name and gender.

**Input**

```
  name  age gender
0    A    1      F
1    B    6      M
2    A    2      F
3    C    3      F
4    A    4      M
```

**Code**

```
df.drop_duplicates(['name', 'gender'], keep='first')
```

**Output**

```
  name  age gender
0    A    1      F
1    B    6      M
3    C    3      F
4    A    4      M
```

Answer (score 2):

result = `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name'], keep='first')`